# Differences between Location and Location CCK?

Tags: 7, location

[Location](http://www.drupal.org/project/location) has three modules: Location, Node Locations and Locations CCK

What are the primary differences between them? Are there any advantages to using Node Locations over the Locations CCK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Location: provides the Location API; handles address storage and geocoding. Essentially the base of the location module to which the other modules rely upon.

Location CCK: provide a Location behavior as a CCK field. This module uses the field API properly rather than its legacy node location module which implemented its own fields and storage.

If you are evaluating which one to use, I would recommend the cck one. The others are being deprecated soon.

Via the [project page](http://www.drupal.org/project/location):

> Location 7.x-4.x is planned to be a stripped out version of location
>   7.x-3.x, which has no node location, user location, location taxonomy (at least in its curren form), location add another sub-modules. It
>   will only have location field, which will essentially be the current
>   location cck module.

Comment: That's helpful! Will leave this question open for another day or two to see if anyone has anything else, will otherwise mark as the answer.

Comment: Not sure what else you were expecting from your question?

Comment: I'm not really sure there is anything more. Mainly I'm curious whether Node Locations has any advantages over Locations CCK, or vice-versa. If not, then your answer is pretty complete.

Comment: IMHO location cck is much better as it actually uses the core field API properly. The node location module is an archaic legacy module that "attached" locations to nodes. It was created back on d5 when there wasnt a consistent way to create fields for custom content types. Hence why it is being deprecated.

Comment: Just the sheer fact that that the node location module is going to be deprecated in the near future should give you the answer you need.

Comment: Yes, but even though something being depreciated in favour of something else implies they're functionally identical or near-identical, this isn't always the case. Regardless, marking this as correct -- doesn't seem like anything else is coming in.

Answer (score -1):

> The Location module allows real-world geographic locations to be
>   associated with Drupal nodes, including people, places, and other
>   content.
>
> **Location**: provides the Location API; handles address storage and
>   geocoding. Allows users to attach locations to nodes.
>
> **User Locations**: allows admins to associate locations with users.
>
> **Location** CCK: provide a Location behavior as a CCK field.

[image]